# Nlohmann::json& as function argument without including json.hpp in header

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, nlohmann-json

I have a class where I want to have a function that uses nlohmann::json& as the argument:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void foo(nlohmann::json& node); 
};
```

But I don't want to include the json.hpp file in my header, just my .cpp. How can I declare the nlohmann::json in the header? I tried:

```
namespace nlohmann
{
    class json;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you give more detail on "doesn't seem to work"? Does it produce a compiler error? Linker error? Incorrect behavior in the function?

Comment: How does it not work? What error are you seeing?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we have a look at the source, we can see that `json` is defined in [json_fwd.hpp](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/7126d88803eeb9d28cc10621f01a58813d50d078/include/nlohmann/json_fwd.hpp#L62).

```
using json = basic_json<>;
```

`json` is an alias for `basic_json` so you need to forward declare `basic_json` before you can declare `json`. If you scroll up a bit in `json_fwd.hpp`, you'll see the massive forward declaration for `basic_json`. So if you want to use `nlohmann::json &` in a header file, you can include `json_fwd.hpp`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without including json_fwd.hpp?

Comment: @ChipBurwell Yes, you can copy-and-paste the contents of `json_fwd.hpp` but that's what `#include` does (and I wouldn't recommend doing that). The `json_fwd.hpp` header is created exactly for this purpose, forwarding `json` without including the gigantic `json.hpp` header.

Answer (score 0):

Please advise what is wrong with my case that does not work.

I have a extracted this minimal example to show the issue:
in my project folder (name is 'ttt'):

```
ttt$ ls
config.cpp  include  main.cpp


ttt$ ls include/
config.h  nlohmann

ls include/nlohmann/
json.hpp  json_fwd.hpp <<<<<These are copied from the 3.11.2 https://github.com/nlohmann/json/releases/tag/v3.11.2


ttt$ cat main.cpp 
#include "config.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Config c("../global_config.json");
  std::cout << c.getParcelCount() << std::endl;
return 0;
}



ttt$ cat config.cpp 
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include "config.h"
#include <fstream>

Config::Config(std::string config_path) {
  std::ifstream f(config_path);
  config_ = json::parse(f);
}




ttt$ cat include/config.h 
#include <nlohmann/json_fwd.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

class Config {
  private:
      json config_;

  public:
    Config(std::string path);
    int getParcelCount() {
      return config_.value("parcel_count", 3);
    }

};
```

Running with following command:

```
g++ config.cpp main.cpp -std=c++17 -I include/
```

I am getting following errors:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
include/config.h:7:9: error: field ‘config_’ has incomplete type ‘json {aka nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<>}’
    json config_;
         ^~~~~~~
In file included from include/config.h:1:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
include/nlohmann/json_fwd.hpp:151:7: note: declaration of ‘using json = using json = class nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<> {aka class nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<>}’
 class basic_json;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I am using g++ 7.5.0 version on Jetson Xavier NX with JetPack 4.6.3

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

If more infor

Comment: You should probably ask a new question rather than piggy back onto this old question. Also, you don't show what config.h is, but the issue is probably in there. Does config.h #include "json_fwd.h"

Comment: You are right, I should have opened a new question. I will update this when I have a little more time than now, as I want to include some additional information that needs more time to be spent. Thanks!